# What i'm doing wrong when implementing Python code to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

I have the next **python** code:

```
letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
word = "Black"
for i in word:
    if i in letter:
        print(i)
```

So, I'm trying to do the same in **JS**:

```
var letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var word = "Black";
var dictionary = [];
var dictionaryCoincidence = [];

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    dictionary.push(word[i]);
}

for (var i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
    if (dictionary[i] == letter[i]) {
        dictionaryCoincidence.push(dictionary[i]);
    }
}

console.log(dictionary);
console.log(dictionaryCoincidence);
```

But, it doesn't work!

Comment: in JS you should use two `for`-loops. First to iterate `dictionary` and second to iterate `letter`.

Comment: `for i in word` is `for(var i of word)` and `i in letter` equivalent is `letter.includes(i)`

Comment: `var letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; var word = "Black"; word.split("").filter(x => letter.includes(x))`

Comment: Inside the for loop, you're comparing `if (dictionary[i] == letter[i])`.  This will only be true if `dictionary` and `word` have the same letter _in the same position_.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if some element belongs to an array, then use a [for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to traverse the string and do something like this:

```js
const letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const word = "Black";

for (const char of word)
{
    if (letter.includes(char))
        console.log(char);
}
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of functional python I suggest using `filter` since it works like the `filter` in python. The question is on both Python and Javascript so :)

```js
var letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var word = "Black";
var filtered = word.split("").filter(x => letter.includes(x))
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need second for loop.. Just check the word[i] is in the letter array or not, and you can do it by using "includes" or "indexOf"..

```js
var letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
        var word = "Black";
        var dictionary = [];
        var dictionaryCoincidence = [];
    
       for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        dictionary.push(word[i]);
        if (letter.includes(word[i])) {
          dictionaryCoincidence.push(dictionary[i]);
        }
       }
       
         console.log(dictionary); console.log(dictionaryCoincidence);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use two loop :
one loop for dictionary and one loop for letters like this:

```
    var letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    var word = "Blackd";
    var dictionary = [];
    var dictionaryCoincidence = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    dictionary.push(word[i]);
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
       for(var j = 0; j < letter.length ; j++){
           if (dictionary[i] == letter[j]) {
             dictionaryCoincidence.push(dictionary[i]);
           }
        }
   }

   console.log(dictionary);
   console.log(dictionaryCoincidence);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the second loop to

```
for (var i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
    if (letter.includes(dictionary[i])) {
        dictionaryCoincidence.push(dictionary[i]);
    }
}
```

You need to check that the dictionary[i] is in the letter array, and not that it equals to letter[i]

1. It gives you the result [a,c] . B is not included, because it’s uppercase.
   Cast dictionary[i] to lowercase if you need the letter B to.
2. You can use letter.indexOf method instead of includes().
   So condition letter.indexOf(dictionary[i])>-1 also works